# Finding the profit between two tables

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Displaying the total profit for each vendor listed in Vendors table
that every product is sold in Products table. Your view column
names should be (name, profit)

Product Table

```
ID      Name   Sell     cost    Quantity V_Id
2008    toy2    25  15    12    1003
2007    toy1    15  5     22    1005
```

Vendor Table

```
V_Id    Name    ZipCode  State
1001    James   07101      NJ
1002    Grant   07811      CA
```

Here's what I have so far but It's not quite working

```
select Vendors.Name, SUM(sell_Price - cost) as Profit
FROM A_Products, A_Vendors
group by Name

Austin  360
Grant   360
James   360
Sam     360
Wendy   360
```

Comment: I wonder who's the *** that rated this negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use explicit join, that way you can avoid ambiguities and more efficient indeed, also use table alias so that it is more readable.

```
SELECT V.Name, SUM(P.sell_Price - P.cost) as Profit 
FROM A_Products P
INNER JOIN A_Vendors V
on P.V_ID=V.V_ID
group by V.Name
```

Comment: Appreciate it thank you for the help. I'm just starting with SQL so i wasn't sure how the format went